# Alpine clear screen before login page s

Tags: alpine-linux

On Linux alpine is it possible to clear the screen before the login prompt is shown.

I cant run commands from inside /etc/issue, so i am stuck in how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can add the clear command to "local" service, as follow:

```
# echo -e "#!/bin/sh\nclear" > /etc/local.d/clearscreen.start
# chmod +x /etc/local.d/clearscreen.start
# rc-update add local
```

The last command is needed to have the "local" service start on boot, since by default is disabled.

More info about local.d (and reccomendation): https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/local.d

.: Francesco

Comment: Hay sadaly no luck the screen dont clear :( before the info in /etc/issues is read)